# Retrieving two highest values from vector

Tags: c++, opencv

I have declared a vector that stores an area of all Bounding Boxes in a given frame. I then used a iterated this vector from beginning to end to retrieve value. I then sorted these values in ascending order (lowest -> highest).

Here is the Code i use:

```
 double area = contourArea(boundingBoxArea);
    list_area.push_back(area);
    sort(list_area.begin(), list_area.end());
    vector<double>::const_iterator area_iter;

    int i = 0;
    for(area_iter = list_area.begin(); area_iter != list_area.end(); area_iter++)
    {
        i++;
        cout<<"Iterator " <<i<< " size is : " <<*area_iter<<endl;
    }
```

My issue is that I am only interested in the last two values out of the set of numbers (2 highest values) but I cant really get my head around it to how should i go about it to achieve my goal.

Anyone out here has a suggestion or solution to my problem...?

Regards

Comment: Use `partial_sort` with the `greater` comparer to sort the two largest values to the front.  Or, just iterate over the list and identify the two largest values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over the list, compare the new value each time against the old highest value. If the new value is higher store it as the highest and have a second variable that that keeps the previous highest value.

Something like this .. may not be syntactically correct but here it is:-

```
   int iCurrentHighest = 0;
    int previousHighest = 0;
    for(area_iter = list_area.begin(); area_iter != list_area.end(); area_iter++)
        {
            if(*area_iter>iCurrentHighest)
            {
              previousHighest  = iCurrentHighest;
              iCurrentHighest = *area_iter;

            }
        else
            {
            if ((*area_iter<iCurrentHighest) && (*area_iter>previousHighest))
                {
                  previousHighest = *area_iter;
                }  
            }

        }
```

Comment: I really lake your solution v.simple and does what id suppose to. Thx

Comment: This is not really correct, each element needs to be compared against the two highest values. Consider for example that the first value in the vector was the highest, then the condition in the `if` would only be met for that first value and no element would be selected as the second highest

Comment: @David Rodríguez , you're correct, I'll update the answer. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Actually i spotted a minor issue with this code, because am doing these operations on a video footage the above coed stores the HIGHEST value of all video footage, so if the next frame has an area of bounding box slightly smaller then then one in previous frame it will not be stored. Where in my video sequence am want to keep a track off the Highest bounding box area per frame not per video footage.

Comment: @Tomazi: That is not an issue with this piece of code, but on your description of the problem. If you want to get the two larger boxes per frame you need to reset the algorithm to the initial state.

Comment: @Tomazi , am I to understand that your list contains multiple frames? If so are the frames of a fixed length or is there a marker in the list which signals the end of a frame and the start of a new frame?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is [std::nth_element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element)

```
    double area = contourArea(boundingBoxArea);
    list_area.push_back(area);
    std::nth_element(list_area.begin(), list_area.begin() + 2, list_area.end(), std::greater<double>());
    // first 2 elements in list_area are now 2 greatest
    vector<double>::const_iterator area_iter;

    int i = 0;
    for(area_iter = list_area.begin(); area_iter != list_area.end(); area_iter++)
    {
        i++;
        cout<<"Iterator " <<i<< " size is : " <<*area_iter<<endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a different version of the algorithm provided by @Rich above with slightly less comparisons (instead of testing each value with the largest and then the second largest, by reversing the order the expected number of comparisons can be reduced: if a number is smaller than the second largest it gets compared only once).

```
int first = 0;
int second = 0;
for (auto const & v : list) {
   if (v > second) {
      second = v;
      if (second > first)
         std::swap(first,second);
   }
}
```

If there is no *known* value that is less than all others, the `first` and `second` values can be initialized with the first two values in the vector (in order).